# Migrate project to Gradle

Tags: android-studio

I've got a project that used to be in Eclipse. I've since moved it from there into Android Studio, though it's not using the Gradle build system yet.

I've setup my gradle files so that I can do `gradlew build` from the command-line and it will generate an APK for me.

My question now is how do I get Android studio to build using the gradle files that I've got setup instead of the using the "old" way?

For what it's worth, I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are compiling the project with Android Studio without actually using Gradle because AFAIK Android Studio always uses Gradle under the hoods to build sources.

Anyway, if you have your Gradle config file ready you only have to import it to a new project in Android Studio (File > Import Project... and then select the `build.gradle` or `settings.gradle`)

Comment: Actually Android Studio uses Ant build when you migrate a project from either Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea. I still use Ant build for my existing projects, because Gradle is the only real "alpha" part of AS - it still needs some time to mature :)

Comment: I've tried this a couple of times... in one case when I choose to use a wrapper, it complains about not being able to create a file named build.grade/.idea. If I don't choose wrapper, it either doesn't work or it opens up a "blank" project -- the only thing I have are a few config files but none of my source.

Comment: Then probably the best idea is exporting from Eclipse to Gradle (in Eclipse, update to the latest SDK Tools, then File > Export... > Android > Generate Gradle build files) and then importing from Gradle to Android Studio (in Android Studio, File < Import project...)